# single file hosted in different .NET Framework in IIS then whole application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6

I have just converted an ASP.NET web application from .NET 3.5 (ASP.NET version 2.0.50727) to .NET4 and at ‘localhost’ development environment everything works fine but after installing the app from a setup (on a test machine running IIS6) one file remains hosted in IIS as in .NET2, thus crashing (with the error: ‘assembly built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded’) and the setting is fixed (I cannot change it from IIS).

All other files in the solution in IIS are automatically hosted in .NET4.

Any idea?

Comment: Remove all the stuff from IIS.Restart the IIS. Once again publish your Framework 4.0 application into one of the specific folder. Then point this folder as physical path in IIS. Set the application pool to ASP.NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Even if it would work, it is not a solution for me as I cannot ask (many) customers to do this as configuring IIS back as it was for other apps (hosting more than my application) would be too much for them.

Comment: Deleting the Virtual Directory of the application in IIS before installing the new version - helped, though it requires a small configuration from a person installing the app post-installation.